# How can i stretch my UV map?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to stretch my uvs so they fit within the texture, however, I can't find a way to do it... i can only resize my uvs
i could stretch them manually but I'm trying to find an easier way

[image: Issue]

This is what I'm getting after resizing the image and re-importing it to blender

[image: Goal]

This is what i want to achieve by stretching my uvs, i just don't know *how* .

( yes I'm quite new to blender )

Comment: Hello :). To stretch your UV map procedurally, you can use the Mapping Node.

Answer (score 1):

In the header of the uv editor you can set the pivot point to your 2d cursor and then place it on one of the right vertices; scaling on the x axis should give you the stretch effect you're looking for

Comment: This isn't the answer that i was looking for.

I'm trying to find a way to stretch it dynamically without disfiguring the uv

Comment: Like i said, i'm looking for a way to stretch it dynamically so the gap between the vertices are still the same

Comment: I'm not sure why you're not satisfied with this answer, if you scale on the X axis (S X) you'll have exactly what you show on picture 2

Answer (score 0):

what if one side doesnt perfectly align with the other, can you move single verticies or faces like press one press other you press some buttonn and then they are in 1 spot instead of having to drag them or is there something simular to that?